# Publicly accessible functions

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating an httphandler.  The file type is probably irrelevant.

My .ashx file:

```
<%@ webhandler class="MyHandler" %>
<%@ assembly src="Functions.vb" %>
<%@ assembly src="Classes.vb" %>

Public Class MyHandler
  ...

End Class
```

My Functions.vb file:

```
Module PublicFunctions

Function SayHello(greeting As String)
  ...

End Function
...

End Module
```

My Classes.vb file:

```
Imports This
Imports That
Imports TheOther
...

Enum AnEnum
End Enum
...

Class AClass
End Class
...
```

In my classes file, I'd like to be able to use the functions in Functions.vb without wrapping them in a class so I can call them directly like

```
SayHello("Hello World")
```

instead of

```
MyPublicFunctions.SayHello("Hello World")
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental idea of object oriented programming.
Every function, every bit of code belongs somewhere and needs to be organized. One way to do this is through the use of objects (classes). If you have a function you would like to preform, conciser what that function is doing and what is using it, and place it in the appropriate place.

I would also suggest not implementing an HttpHandler. In the Asp.Net framework, just about anything you would ever want a web app to do is already handled by something somewhere. I've been on a lot of web projects, and every time I see someone trying to write one, their is always another (usually out of the box) way to do it.

Comment: You're probably right about the OO aspects... my middle layer was originally written in classic ASP and it's been a long, painful process to convert it to .NET.  I originally converted to .aspx where I could continue to use my vb functions w/o a class wrapper.  The HttpHandler makes sense for my purposes because I'm responding to AJAX posts with text - there are no web controls, etc.  This final bit of conversion has forced me fully into .NET and it's taken a bit of getting used to.

Comment: Working with legacy systems is always a challenge. I certainly do not envy you. If you write a HttpHandler that needs to say `"Hello World"` would it not make sense to put that function in your handler?

Comment: My function library contains 285 subs & functions.  Most of them need to be refactored into classes but some of them are more generic.  Yesterday, I figured out how to extend the base classes.  All the really generic functions will be converted to base class extensions.  I just have to whittle my way through that library and find the generics.  This phase has turned into quite the learning experience for me.

Comment: Learning experiences have always been the fun part of developing for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could turn "SayHello" into an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) with the type of the handler as the parameter type but you'll probably still have to specify `Me.SayHello()`.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
Imports PublicFunctions
```

help at all?

**EDIT** - since that didn't work, try converting PublicFunctions to a class, make its members Shared (so that they work without an instance of the class, the equivalent of c# static), and do the import. This is working for me, although I am not in an ASP environment.

Comment: I gave it a shot, but no.  It accepts the Imports just fine but still errors on the function call.  Also tried changing the functions wrapper from Module PublicFunctions to Class PublicFunctions.